# What is changing the size of this "span"?

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML webpage with both English and Portuguese languages, that are swapped when I press a flag at the top of the page. This is done through a class in a `span`. Typical usage:

```
  <div>
  <span class="por1">Portuguese text 1</span>
  <span class="eng1">English text 2</span>
  Some text 3 that is correct in both languages
  </div>
```

By default, I have in CSS (English is the default language):

```
  .por1 { display: none }
  .eng1 { display: inline-block }
```

When I press the flag, the languages are swapped using obvious javascript.

This works perfect in a desktop, no errors in `W3C`, but **in mobile devices (only)** the texts 1 and 2 inside both `spans` is smaller than text 3. I erased all the `@media`, and the thing still gives problems.

However, if I erase the two CSS lines `.por1` and `.eng1` above, of course both texts 1 and 2 appear simultaneously, but now with the correct size. Hence, it seems to have something to do with the `display` tag...?

Hence, the behaviour is as I have two spans `.por1` and `.eng1` CSS for mobile devices, but I have not. In fact, debugging the page in Chrome shows that the two spans have no special formatting.

[This is the page](http://luis.impa.br/photo/000_borboletas_mariposas.html). Take a look at it in a smartphone and you will see two different sizes in the title already.

**EDIT** I simplified the page to the maximum. Look at the page now, whose complete code is this, including CSS:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Crazy</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<style type="text/css">
 body { font-size: 24px; }
 .por1 { display: none }
 .eng1 { display: inline-block }
 h2 { font-size: 2em; }
 h3 { font-size: 1.7em; }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<h2> <span class="por1">Borboletas e Mariposas</span><span class="eng1">Butterflies and Moths</span> <br> (Rhopalocera, Heterocera) </h2>

<h3> oplus <span class="por1">Borboletas     </span><span class="eng1">Butterflies  </span> (Papilionoidea) </h3>

<div class="inner"><span class="por1">asa-de-vidro   </span><span class="eng1">Glasswing    </span> (Greta sp.)</div>
<div class="inner"><span class="por1">mariposa-walker</span><span class="eng1">Walker's moth</span> (Lepidoptera, Erebidae: Sosxetra grata)</div>
<div class="inner"><span class="por1">mariposa       </span><span class="eng1">herilia moth </span> (Erebidae: Letis sp. (herilia?))</div>

</body></html>
```

If I remove the fist `<div class="inner">`, the page is still rendered with crazy font sizes. But if I remove the second, or the third, the page is rendered correctly (??!!). In fact, if I remove `(herilia?)` from the third `<div class="inner">`, it is also rendered correctly!! Actually, if I remove the `?` it is also rendered correctly. Same happens if I remove the `oplus`. No idea what is happening!

**EDIT 2**

Screenshot of the wrong rendering:

[image: Screenshot of the wrong rendering]

Screenshot of the correct rendering (same HTML code with the `(herilia?)` removed):

[image: Screenshot of the correct rendering]

**EDIT 3** If I change `h3 { font-size: 1.7em; }` to `h3 { font-size: 1.5em; }`, the problem is gone!

Comment: can you take a screenshot of the problem, compare what looks incorrect with what looks correct... as I cannot seem to find any difference viewing the page on my phone and on my pc or my laptop

Comment: Please, see my EDIT 2.

Comment: This is interesting indeed... I don't have this problem when viewing in chrome... will check out the page in other browsers? what browser are you using?

Comment: The problem only happens in MOBILE devices. I am using Chrome 54 in Android.

Comment: Luis, I couldn't reproduce the problem on my mobile device... all I can suggest that could result in this display issue, is the usage of the rem unit.

Comment: Changing `rem` to `em` gives the same issue. If I change `h3 { font-size: 1.7em; }` to `h3 { font-size: 1.5em; }`, the problem is gone!

Comment: @Hallur: please, look at the page now in your mobile. The complete code with CSS is above and very short. Which mobile do you use?

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude Fantastic, it works like a charm! I added it also to the `h2` and `h3` elements of the title, and also corrected those. Quite a crazy thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are experiencing a problem that I experiment in the past. It's the **autoadjusting** of the font size setted by webkit mobile browsers.

I usually use this trick to avoid autosizing

```
 div { max-height: 9999px; }
```

You can apply to the div or the spans, try and tell me what is the result.

### Edit

You need to make this kind of tricks too avoid the effect. The problem seems to be something about the bad viewport configuration and texts below 18 pixels. The browser thinks that is a text that the user can't read and apply autosizing to allow user to read it.

Comment: I love you. :) Yeah!! But what bug is that?? I will deleted my answer.

Comment: Is not a bug, is a feature, but it doesn't work very well. I hate that but it's impossible to deactivate. You need to make this kind of tricks too avoid the effect. The problem seems to be something about the bad viewport configuration and texts below 18 pixels. The browser thinks that is a text that the user can't read and apply autosizing to allow user to read it. I will add this to the answer

Comment: Great. Hope this saves the time of someone else, since it trashed several hours of mine. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I was stucked on an important project about 5 days with this crap. I understand you. My investigation work is one of the most obscured investigation on my web development life. LOL

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify the font-size for your span tags

Comment: Not an option. those spans appear in different context and different sizes.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you well, you know you can play with the font size in CSS, but you don't want to, as I understood from one of your comments.

I suggest controlling the font size through javascript dynamically to fit your multiple contexts, if you need any help with that just let us know.

Comment: That would be extremely cumbersome, and very difficult to maintain. Please, look at my EDIT and the 10 page complete HTML without any JS that is still crazy....